# which language to choose for interactive graphic widget in windows

Tags: windows, widget, interactive, graphic

I need to make a small widget in windows.

The basic requirement is, use a few buttons to control a graphic (a few lines) based on some math functions and another button to import those values into an .mdb or .csv database.

Ff possible, to listen to a DDE data server from another application.

What's the quickest language to use for this application?

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the answer is C#. Microsoft has worked a lot on the UI builder, which comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: Alex, do you mean to build a excel template in c#? I'm trying to get away from excel because of speed concern.

Comment: In that case, you can check the following frameworks: [Of](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) , [cinder](http://libcinder.org/)  and [Processing](https://processing.org/)